# Extending module when entire module imported

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend the `d3` library with a new function in typescript but I'm running into a problem with figuring out the syntax. d3 is shipped as a collection of functions which are exported meaning you import it  as

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

I've tried extending it as I would a static

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';


function contextMenuFn() {
    console.log('hey, I'm a context menu!');
}

d3.contextMenu = contextMenuFn;

declare module 'd3' {
    namespace d3 {
        export let contextMenu: typeof contextMenuFn;
    }
}
```

However, the compiler rejects that as contextMenu doesn't exist on d3. What's the right syntax here?

**Update**: I also tried

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

function contextMenuFn() {
    console.log('hey, context menu!');
}

d3.contextMenu = contextMenuFn;

declare module 'd3' {
    export let contextMenu: typeof contextMenuFn;
}
```

but that reported "Cannot assign to 'contextMenu' because it is constant or read-only property"

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?